# Basic PHP collection

Tags: php

I have an entry that could have several comments associated with that entry.

If I were doing this in C# I would build a collection of these comments.  However, I'm unfamiliar with a way to do this in PHP.

My current thought process is to have a comment object that has a method that would build and data_array based off of IDs and then just call that object and utilize the data that way.

Is that the easiest most basic way of doing that?  Or is there a better (right way) of building a collection for PHP?

**My pseudo code:**

```
class entry
var $id
var $text


class comments
var $id
var $entryId
var $text
var $data_array;

function getCollectionById(){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $da[$i] = array('entryId'=>$row["entryId"],'text'=>$text);
    }
    $this->data_array = $da;
}
```

Comment: You can build a Class, just like you mentioned above and use it like you want to. You can also write constructors to assign initial values to the object members.

Comment: `class entry` would expose a value of type `array` with the comments for that entry. There are several choices regarding how the array will be exposed (a normal property, either eagerly or lazily loaded; a "virtual" property implemented using `__get`; an explicit getter function), but the idea is the same.

Comment: That rather looks like a Table Data Gateway or an ActiveRecord to me. Maybe you really want to have a Repository?

Comment: @Gordon - Can you explain your ideas a little more?  I'm not familiar with what you are saying.

Comment: see http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrays can simulate collections very effectively:

```
$my_collection = array();

// some loop to populate your collection

$my_collection[] = new Comment(...); // adds a new object to the end of the collection

//end loop
```

you can loop through it with foreach

```
foreach($my_collection as $comment):
   print_r($comment);
endforeach;
```